# What do I type in SSRS's "Query Designer"'s "Define Query Parameters" to get an array?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    someTable
WHERE
    id IN (@EngineType_ids)
```

The query works just fine. I can setup parameters with multi-select all working perfectly. My question is:  **What do I type in the box to get SSRS to return multiple results?** (A single integer work fine. I simply cannot communicate to this dialog box that the string I am typing should not be parsed as a single integer)

(I cannot post an image. Image can be found here instead: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zywCl.jpg)

- =Split("1,2,3",",") does not work
- (1,2,3) does not work
- [1,2,3] does not work
  All result in the entire string trying to be parsed as a single integer

Answer (score 0):

Try 1,2,3 (without the brackets)